# Android - create TextView (or EditText) programmatically and set it in a specific place on the screen giving coordinates

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, coordinates

I am building an android app where the user paints some objects in the screen. One type of object is a Text object. The user creates the object by dragging his finger and the object is shown as a rectangle that can be moved/reshaped. When user taps the text object, I launch a new activity where user enters text which I return on the onActivityResult method.

Now I want to show the text in the object. I can have access to stuff as the coordinates of the Rectangle etc from my text class. What I want to do in essence, is to create a TextView (or EditText) programmatically and set its bounds as the bounds of my rectangle that my object is painted in. Is there a method that can help me do it?

(another approach would be to use the canvas.drawTextOnPath method in my text object. But this seems more complicated since my text might get out of the object, and I would also have to handle the multilines)

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: trying GAMA's approach

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {                 
  switch(requestCode) { 
  case 1:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
            String text=data.getStringExtra("text");
            System.out.println(text);
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            //LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams((int)texts.get(index).width,(int)texts.get(index).height));
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(100,100));
            //tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //lp.setMargins((int)texts.get(index).Sx, (int)texts.get(index).Sy, (int)texts.get(index).Lx, (int)texts.get(index).Ly);

            tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            tv.setTextSize(10);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            tv.setText(text);
            lp.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
            //tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("got "+tv.getText());
            }
      break;
      }
  }
```

both prints show the text as expected but I do not see anything in the screen (tried to set it on the bottom left to begin with)

Comment: r u getting correct results at `System.out.println(text);` and `System.out.println("got "+tv.getText());` ???

Comment: yes both.. The string as I gave it to the child activity

Comment: Sorry mate. I have no idea what might be the cause. I can suggest u 2 try out `canvas.drawTextOnPath` as suggested by urself earlier

Comment: hi again, one question can you tell me which import you use so that the LayoutParams can be recognized? (I doubt that the problem is there, but..)

Comment: Depends on you Layout. It can be `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` or `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`...

Comment: you mean the root element of the views xml? That is what I thought but tried both with no luck..

Comment: Yes, *the root element of the views xml*... That should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `drawTextOnPath` is your best bet. It won't bleed out. All you have to do is create a path that goes from the left, center vertical of your rectangle to the right center vertical. The method will take care of resizing the text so that it will stay within the Path.

You can adjust the path accordingly by using `Paint.getTextWidth()`. If the width is bigger than the box, extend your path with a line `Paint.getTextHeight()` below the first line.

Comment: thank you, but I think that this way if the text is bigger than the rectangle can hold, some letters will just not be shown. I want it to go to a second line. Which I think can be done, but it is complex to calculate the width of the text, also of the object and set the paths accordingly. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Calculating text width is easy. There is a method in paint for it. I added the code.

Comment: yes that is what I thought of doing. The complexity lies in that I want the text to be alligned in center of the box, so if I have a second line, I have to move first path up a bit and add the second right below. If I have 3rd or 4th line it goes on. I know it can be done, I just wanted a TextView to handle it for me:)

Answer (score 10):

```
                    EditText edText = new EditText(this);
            edText .setId(i);
            edText .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    1f));

                    edText .setWidth(100);
            edText .setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            edText .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            edText .setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
            edText .setMaxLines(1);
                    edText .setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
            edText .setOnEditorActionListener(this);
            edText .addTextChangedListener(this);

                    //this linearlayout id is declared inside your xml file
                        LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
                        linear.addView(edText );
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it. Where in this do I define the bounds of the EditText?

Comment: Suppose you want to create EditText when you click on the button . then you have to write above inside that button click listner and then you click the button edittext created for you and one more think when edittext is create to have to add this edittext inside any layout in your layout.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(width,height));
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I try this but the text is not displayed. As width and height I give the width and height of my rectangle and in the lp.setMargins I give (int left, int top, int right, int bottom) of my rectangle. And then     tv.setText(text); am I missing something?

Comment: yes I set also 
tv.setTextSize(15);
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

Comment: I also logged the value and it is ok

Comment: please check my edit where I added the code. Do I do something wrong? On the background there is an image so it should be visible (other red letters are)