# Android - Create Text Box object, like the one that microsoft word provides

Tags: android, textbox, android-edittext, textview

This one bothers me for quite a while. I have an app where the user paints some objects with fingers. One is supposed to be a Text Box, a rectangular where the user can input text, like the one word provides (http://www.techrepublic.com/i/tr/cms/contentPics/r00319991202jod05_01.gif)
I do not need the text to be painted dynamically, I launch another activity where the user adds text and I catch the text on activity result. But I need the user to be able to reshape the object and it should handle all the cases like:

i.  Box too narrow for the text -> get the last words to another line

ii. Box too narrow for some single words -> split the words

I want to handle this exactly like word text box handles it. I thought it could me by dynamically making a textView, but it seems impossible. I posted a question here [Android - create TextView (or EditText) programmatically and set it in a specific place on the screen giving coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894733/android-create-textview-or-edittext-programmatically-and-set-it-in-a-specifi) (mostly about textView) but I had no luck, drawTextOnPath can work for i but it is very hard to implement ii and show text in a smooth way.

I know we are not supposed to ask the same thing twice, but I do it to explain in a new way what I need, which leads to a different question. Thanks to everybody in advance.

Comment: I am also interested on this kind of task. I wanted to create a EditText that can allow the user to insert pictures, videos, audio right on the EditText view.

Answer (score 0):

- Moving the Text around can be done easily by dragging the view in `onTouchEvent`.
- Scaling the text can be done using two finger gesture. Just like the zoom feature in `Webview`. You should increase the *textsize* of the `TextView` on zoom-in and decrease on zoom-out.

### Update:

- Resize the `TextView` itself when two finger gesture is on. That will automatically re-flow the text appropriately. `TextView` can be resized by calling `setHeight` and `setWidth`.
- Declare a `LinearLayout` with `TextView` as the only child.
- Inflate this layout when needed and set the margins for the textview to position it appropriately.
- When resizing just change the *height* and *width* of the textview.

Comment: I can move the object and the text easily. On scaling I want a fixed text size, but to be handled in a way the is fitted in the box every time. Exactly how the word text box handles things

Comment: resize the textview itself. reflowing the text inside the textview will be taken careof automatically..

Comment: You mean that I have to create a TextView programmatically exactly in the place where the user painted the rectangular object? And then display the text there. That is what I tried but it does not work (see also the link in the original post). I can reshape my object at will and obtain all the coos I need.  
Do you have some codelines that explains how to properly do this? Maybe I am missing something simple, but I searched all over and I am stuck.

Comment: Please add your best try to your post so that I can find out why that did not work..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894733/android-create-textview-or-edittext-programmatically-and-set-it-in-a-specifi
Here I have an edit on the post where I try an approach. I try to create the textView and display the text there. I tried set the text view to the desired rectangular but also somewhere else just for text. No matter what I try the text does not appear though the prints on log show that it was retrieved properly and it is assigned to the textView

Comment: Try the steps I have suggested.

Comment: I tried a lot of things with no success. Now I noticed this I have these lines 
System.out.println((int)width);
tv.setWidth((int)width);
System.out.println("width="+tv.getWidth());
width is the width of the object and the first print looks completely ok. But tv.getWidth() gives always 0. How is this possible (the same happens with the height)?

Comment: Have you added the textView to a layout?

Comment: Yes, I tried both to create a LinearLayout dynamically, and to add it to my RelativeLayout from the corresponding xml.

Comment: You can directly add it to your relativlayout. I was asking only to know if it has a parent layout or not.